# How can I access parent model value in VueJS2?

Tags: javascript, laravel, eloquent, vuejs2

I'm sure I'm not the only one who has this issue with VueJS2.

I use axios to return an array of "persons", how can I access the "name" attribute from person's parent model, company?

In laravel I can access it like this:
$person -> company -> name

But if i do person.company.name in VueJs2, it gives an error.
Please help, thanks a lot!

The error is:

```
vue.js:526 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at eval (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:9263), <anonymous>:2:662)
at Proxy.renderList (vue.js:3647)
at Proxy.eval (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:9263), <anonymous>:2:507)
at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.js:3873)
at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.js:2419)
at Watcher.get (vue.js:2756)
at Watcher.run (vue.js:2826)
at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.js:2595)
at Array.<anonymous> (vue.js:658)
at nextTickHandler (vue.js:605)
```

Here's the code I use to create "persons" response

```
$searchterms = explode(' ',$searchterm);

$person = (new Person)->newQuery();

foreach($searchterms as $searchterm) {
    $person -> WhereHas('company', function($query) use($searchterm) {
        $query->where('name','like','%'.$searchterm.'%');
    });
}

$persons = $person -> get();

return $persons;
```

Comment: This question is currently impossible to answer. What **exactly** is the error? How are you retrieving the *persons* data? What is the data structure for each *person*? How are you constructing the data server-side?

Comment: My guess is the *company* property is a lazy-loaded relation and you're not including it when creating the *persons* response

Comment: HI Phil, yes that's likely to be the cause as I ran a query on child model and returned the results directly. it would be nice if you can tell me how i can load it properly with the child?

Comment: Post your PHP code that you use to create the *persons* response. I don't know Eloquent very well but I'm sure somebody else here does

Comment: HI Phil, thanks for the advice, I've added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [*Eager Loading*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), it seems you should be using something like

```
$persons = $person->with('company')->get();
```